# feathersjs: How do I pass un-opinionated errors back to client

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

Seems like error messages are wrapped in text.  Say in a model validation I just want to send "exists" to the client if a record already exists.

One the server maybe I do something like:

```
validate: {
        isEmail: true,
        isUnique: function (email, done) {
          console.log("checking to see if %s exists", email);
          user.findOne({ where: { email: email }})
            .then(function (user) {
                done(new Error("exists"));
            },function(err) {
                console.error(err);
                done(new Error('ERROR: see server log for details'));
              }
            );
        }
      }
```

On the client maybe I do:

```
feathers.service('users').create({
      email: email,
      password: password
    })
      .then(function() {
        console.log("created");
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.error('Error Creating User!');
        console.log(error);
      });
```

The error printed to console is:

> "Error: Validation error: exists"

How to I just send the word "exists" without the extra text?  Really I'd like to send back a custom object, but I can't seem to find any examples of doing this.  The closest I've seen is this: https://docs.feathersjs.com/middleware/error-handling.html#featherserror-api

But I haven't figured out how to make something like this work in the validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feathers does not change any error messages so the `Validation error:` prefix is probably added by Mongoose.

If you want to change the message or send an entirely new error object, as of feathers-hooks v1.6.0 you can use error hooks:

```
const errors = require('feathers-errors');

app.service('myservice').hooks({
  error(hook) {
    const { error } = hook;

    if(error.message.indexOf('Validation error:') !== -1) {
      hook.error = new errors.BadRequest('Something is wrong');
    }
  }
});
```

You can read more about error and application hooks [here](https://blog.feathersjs.com/feathers-application-and-error-hooks-7a5982e70024#.mid30uph6)